# Questions on Spherical Symmetry

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

One can say a symmetric and uniform distribution of n points on a 2D circle can be simply obtained by using n identical circular sectors.

We can also say that for a 3-dimensional sphere, there exists a symmteric and uniform distribution of 4 points, which forms a tetrahedron.

While there are 5 platonic solids in 3D, I was guessing that a 'good symmetric' distribution can only be achieved with these 5 orientations.

Here are my questions.

1. Is it possible to place 5 points on a 3D sphere so that they are symmetrical? How about n points?

(By 'symmetrical', it has to be possible to rotate the sphere to match the previous 'shape' but the name of the points should be different)

2. What happens if the problem is extended to a k-dimensional sphere?

You may change/modify the definition of symmetrical distribution if that makes this question clearer.

P.S. I am sorry but my english is not that good, so it might be hard to understand my words here. Also, I would prefer elementary explanations as I am a high school student though advanced solutions are also welcomed. (I will try my best to understand the solutions!)

Comment: The answer is yes, but you won't like it: just put all 5 points on a great circle!

Comment: I get it, then what constraints can be added in order to emphasize "3D"?

Comment: Simply add the condition "not all on the same circle". However, in this case, I believe your intuition is correct that only the vertices of a platonic solid will work. For each set of 3 adjacent points, you can slice the sphere with a plane (3 points are adjacent if there are no other points on the removed slice). Once you've done all slices, the symmetry requires all edges and faces of the remaining figure to be congruent. I.e., a regular solid, which must be convex because of the adjacency of the points defining the planes. I.e. a platonic solid.

Comment: I guess that is the right answer, but that still leaves me with a question that uses a physical intuition. What would happen if 5 particles that pushes each other (e.g 5 electrons) are placed on a sphere?

Comment: The arrangement does not have to be completely symmetrical to minimize the forces. For example 3 electrons equally spaced on the equator and the other 2 are at the poles is an equilibrium position (though I am not sure it is a stable equilibrium), even though the situation of the pole electrons is not the same as the equator electrons.

Comment: See [**Thomson Problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem)

Comment: This question has been asked many times on this forum and on others these last years. Here are some of them. It will give you as well an idea of the keywords to be used: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805583/dispersing-n-points-uniformly-on-a-sphere) (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/212550/distributing-points-evenly-on-a-sphere), etc...

Comment: Thank you for all people who helped me!

Comment: It's a pleasure to help people like you still in high school that are asking themselves important questions. Keep going!