# Finding symmetrical bumpy sphere

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry, spherical-geometry

This is a bit of a strange question; I am not sure of some of the correct terminology and so there may be a solution already that I cannot find; I apologize in advance if this is the case. The [bumpy sphere](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~groberts/Courses/MA241/Labs/Lab3.pdf) $1+a\sin n\theta\sin m\varphi$ is not symetrical about the bumps and has points at the [poles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NorthPole.html) where the surface becomes 'bunched up'. I have tried (purely from interest) to find an $r(\theta,\varphi)$ defining a bumpy sphere that is symmetrical about each of the bumps but failed. I have tried to formalize my question as follows:

For what $n\ge3$ is the following definition of a function $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $S$ is the [unit sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere) possible?

> 1. Let $b_k,\;k\in{1,2,...,n}$ be points on $S$ (not all on a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle)) such that for all $(b_i,b_j)$ any [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation) $R$ satisfying $Rb_i=b_j$ has the property that $R\{b_k\}=\{b_k\}$.
> 2. Let $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a [non-constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_function) function such that for all $(b_i,b_j)$ any rotation $R$ satisfying $Rb_i=b_j$ has the property that for all $p\in S$ we have $f(p)=f(Rp)$. In some sense, $f$ should also be [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness).
> 3. Ideally I would like the following to hold: For any $b_k$ let $\operatorname{close}(b_k)$ be the set of all $b_i$ that are [minimally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization) distant along the sphere from $b_k$; then for all $b_k$ we should have that for any $b_i\in\operatorname{close}(b_k)$ the graph of $f$ on the [minor arc](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinorArc.html) of the [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) connecting $b_i$ and $b_k$ should have [global maxima](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlobalMaximum.html) at its endpoints and a unique [local minimum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LocalMinimum.html) between them.

What I am trying to require by the **first** point is that we have points equally distributed on $S$ such that their arrangement is preserved by any rotation mapping one to the other. I'm sure this is possible for $n=6$ but I'm not sure about other $n$; [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021173/questions-on-spherical-symmetry) unanswered question asks about this and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212550/distributing-points-evenly-on-a-sphere) question may be relevant. The **second** point is trying to find a smooth non-constant function that also satisfies this rotation [invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)); again I do not know if this is possible. The **third** point is trying to establish that $f$ should be maximized at the $b_k$ and minimized in between. The picture in my head is of a [sine-ish](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin(x)sin(y)) function on the sphere where the maxima are at the $b_i$ and the function is symmetrical about the $b_i$ (the connection to the bumpy sphere is that we could translate and scale $f$ to get an $r(\theta,\varphi)$). Apologies if I haven't been clear.

My **questions** are: For which (if any) $n$ is the given construction possible? If we remove requirement 3 does it become possible? Is there any way of relaxing the conditions slightly to create an $f$ that corresponds to the idea I have described? Can any such function for some $n$ have a simple representation, say in terms of [trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions)?

Comment: It sounds like the first requirement necessitates that you get subgroups of the rotation group. There are only a [few different ones](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_subgroups_of_SO(3,R)). A requirement that any vertex can be carried into any other would further imply that you can only have bumps at the vertices of the platonic solids.

Comment: It appears that this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01348 gives functions which are invariant under octahedral, tetrahedral, etc. groups.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy That makes sense. Thanks for the link; I'll have a closer read of it later.